# When inserting code in AndroidManifest.xml, my app stops

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, fullscreen

My Manifest runs like this;

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"          
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"   
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"    
         >                               
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>    
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

But deleting android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" in activity, it works. It's about one month that I am struggling with this in Eclipse. Any advice will be welcomed.

Comment: In which device are you running that. Can you replace the theme with `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried Theme.Black. But it doesn't work.

Comment: As mentioned above, when I insert android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" or something like that, Unfortunately my app has stopped.

Comment: I have inserted that code in <application> and <activity>, neither of which doesn't work. I am dying.

Comment: please post the whole manifest including header xml version

Comment: When I try to attach the whole manifest, it says "too long". What can I do with that? Sorry I am new to this site. Could you show me how I can post the Whole manifest? Is it possible in Comment box? Sorry again.

Comment: Upper part of manifest which you can not see is ;

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nc2.hotspot"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

Comment: it's weird. Can you try running the application from commandline. without using eclipse

Comment: Whether from commandline or eclipse, it doesn't work. I've made my app watching Youtube video : www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uc9-JrEy8vw. In the video, he inserted that code and it worked. It's weird to me, too.